# See where a URL ends without letting know the tracker..!

Tags: email, url

In my email I have a URL like this:

```
https://signl.live/tracker/click?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ilovefreesoftware.com%2F&dID=1537935418274&linkName=https://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/
```

Now, if I click on it then the tracker will know that I actually clicked on it. But I don't want that. Is there any way to reach the target URL without letting know the tracker ?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the tracker is only reading the URL parameters, not transforming them or trying to trick you, then you can read the value without clicking anything.

`www.ilovefreesoftware.com`

I did not visit that site and I'm not sure that I would recommend it either.

---

The URL parameters are everything that comes after the `?` in the original link.

- `redirect`: `hxxps://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/`
- `dID`: `1537935418274`
- `linkName`: 'hxxps://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/'

*NOTE: I've changed `https` to `hxxps` so that the link is not clickable in this post.*

Perhaps you were thrown off by the url encoding (e.g. `https%3A%2F%2Fwww`).  The content between `http` and `www` in that string are [hexadecimal numbers representing ascii characters](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).  The number `0x3A` represents the character `:` and `0x2F` is `/`.

---

If the tracking server is trying to trick you or obscure the true destination then you have to let it run to find out what it does.  No free software is worth the risk though.

Good luck!